# Restoring a Particular User's mdbox Mailbox in Dovecot

Tags: email, imap, dovecot

A user is reporting lost emails due to a client-side error, so I need to restore emails from backup for this particular user but I'm not finding anything online (maybe my google-fu is lame).

Basically, the mailbox is in mdbox format:

```
mdbox:/marchive/%n/mdbox:LAYOUT=fs
```

`maildata1` is served from an NFS export from a NetApp appliance which snapshots on a weekly basis. I wanted to revert a particular user's mailbox to the state it was in last week (which I have file-level access to) but I'm unable to find what the general procedure for doing such is. My interest is in finding the proper way to swap out their current mailbox for this older one.

Is it as simple as copying the files over with `rsync -aS` ?

This is on dovecot 2.0.9 and RHEL 6.5 if that makes a difference.

Comment: Do you guys backup the entire mailbox (including indexes, uidvalidity,cache files etc.) or just m.* files?

Comment: We have the entire directory, indexes and all.

Comment: Then all you have to do is just backup the current directories and put the files from backup in correct directories and set the permissions accordingly. It dont even require a resync

Comment: @clement can you post this as an answer so I can accept it?